# Map<String, Deque<Block>> value help needed

Tags: java, collections

I am a beginner so please be easy on me. I have to create a Stocks program that would store different 3-letter stock codes, stock prices, and purchase prices. Then recall them to sell at a different price. My issue is that I can't seem to be able to properly add more stock value to the Map. When I put a different value in it erases the first value, or at least it appears to. My Block Class (NOT LISTED) returns the newest key and values to the code listed below. My code and results are listed below:

```
    private String getPurchaseMap(String stockCode, Double quantityPurchased, Double purchasePrice) {
            var stock = new Block(stockCode, quantityPurchased, purchasePrice);
            var deque = new ArrayDeque<Block>();


           if (!maintainStocks.containsKey(stockCode)) {
               deque = new ArrayDeque<Block>();
               deque.offerFirst(stock);
               maintainStocks.put(stockCode, deque);
           } else {

               deque.offer(stock);
               maintainStocks.put(stockCode, deque);
           }

                var tempObj = maintainStocks.get(stockCode).peekFirst();
                for (var stocks : maintainStocks.entrySet()) {
                    System.out.printf("%s%n", stocks.getKey());

                    for (var test : stocks.getValue()) {
                        System.out.println(tempObj.getQuantity());
                        System.out.println(tempObj.getPrice());
                    }
                }

                return null;
        }

    The results are:
    -Would you like to (B)uy, (S)ell stock or (E)xit? > b
    -Please enter the 3-letter stock code > aaa
    -Please enter the quantity to purchase > 10
    -Please enter the price per share > 15
    -aaa
    -10.0
    -15.0
    -Would you like to pursue another transaction? (Y)es or (N)o > y
    -Would you like to (B)uy, (S)ell stock or (E)xit? > b
    -Please enter the 3-letter stock code > aaa
    -Please enter the quantity to purchase > 11
    -Please enter the price per share > 16
    -aaa
    -11.0
    -16.0
    -Would you like to pursue another transaction? (Y)es or (N)o > n
    -Thank you for your consideration. Solution exiting.
```

Comment: You're probably modifying a single instance of a class, instead of having multiple instances (created with `new`). While it may then seem you have multiple objects in your map, you've actually put the same object multiple times, hence the "change one and others change too" appearance.